# Custom template for custom page in custom module in D6

Tags: theming, 6, routes

So I know there is a way to specify a custom template for custom content types etc, but if I have a custom module where I am using hook_menu() to add custom pages with a page callback function, how can I specify that the pages I create use a custom template? This particular site is still on Drupal 6, so I would need to know the Drupal 6 method if it's possible

THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have something like this:

```
function YOURMODULE_menu() {

  $items=array();

  $items['yourmodule/cool/path'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'YOURMODULE_cool_path_callback',
    // etc
  );

  // etc

  return $items;

}
```

then Drupal will utilize `page-yourmodule-cool-path.tpl.php` (eg, the `/`s are turned into `-`s) if it exists without any further action besides clearing your caches to pick it up.

In fact, if you create a `page-yourmodule.tpl.php` file, Drupal will use it for ANY path starting with `yourmodule`, eg, `yourmodule/cool/path`, `yourmodule/cooler/path,` etc., that doesn't have a more specific template created for it.

See [Drupal 6 Template Suggestions](https://drupal.org/node/1089642) for more info.

But, of course, if you have lots of paths that you want to use a single custom page template for that aren't so similarly defined, you can certainly use [hook_preprocess_page()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/6) to suggest a non-standard template file:

```
function YOURMODULE_OR_THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

  if (/* whatever is true */) {
    $variables['template_files'][] = 'page-custom';
  }

}
```

which would then have Drupal using `page-custom.tpl.php` for whatever was true in that `if`. Just realize if `custom` is defined as a path somewhere on your system, or is the start of a path, Drupal will use this template there as well.

Just realize somewhat obviously that whichever route you take, the page templates reside in your theme's directory and not with your module unless you use a registry alter:

```
function YOURMODULE_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $theme_hook = 'page'; 
  $modulepath = drupal_get_path('module', 'YOURMODULE') . '/tpl/page';
  array_unshift($theme_registry[$theme_hook]['theme paths'], $modulepath);
}
```

which *should* cause Drupal to look in a `tpl/page` directory of your module for them but this brings up all sorts of other issues.

Comment: Ok so the funny thing is, that's what I thought and that is what I tried FIRST. I just created a template file page-MYCUSTOMPAGE.tpl.php, but no matter how many times I cleared the cache and no matter what I had in template.php, it would NOT get honored... So after messing with it, I decided to try a different alias and it worked! So here is what I found out and I'm not sure if I am crazy or not, but my original path ended in a number. Just for a test I created a path called "jobsearchresults2" and that was the one that would not work no matter what...

Comment: I then changed the path to "foo" and my template file to "foo.tpl.php" and it was fine. I think it was the fact that my path had a number in it. Again I could be crazy but a path with a number did not work but the path without one did. Anyway, I have it working now. THANKS GUYS!

Comment: Numbers as path elements are ignored/special within Drupal.  Read the Template Suggestions link above for more information about them, but glad it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom callback functions still use url aliases so you would just need to define a preprocess_hook that adds template files if that particular alias is being served. Here is a basic function you can use in your template.php file, modified from [this handbook page](https://drupal.org/node/139766):

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

    $alias = drupal_get_path_alias(str_replace('/edit','',$_GET['q']));

    if (($alias != $_GET['q']) && ($alias == 'YOUR CUSTOM HOOK')) {;
      $template_filename = 'page' . '-' . 'YOUR CUSTOM TEMPLATE';
      $vars['template_files'][] = $template_filename;
    }

}
```

So, for example, if your menu hook was /trigger/awesome then the code could look like this:

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

    $alias = drupal_get_path_alias(str_replace('/edit','',$_GET['q']));

    if (($alias != $_GET['q']) && ($alias == 'trigger/awesome')) {;
      $template_filename = 'page' . '-' . 'awesome';
      $vars['template_files'][] = $template_filename;
    }

}
```

and the theme would now look to serve this page using the page-awesome.tpl.php file in your theme folder.